# Jinja2 escaping object passed to templare.render

Tags: jinja2

I created a class representing an input widget and I'd like to use if directly in the template. However, whenever I pass it to the template it gets escaped.

```py
class Widget:
    def render(self):
        Markup('<input type="text">')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.render()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.render()

widget = Widget()
widget  # <input type="text">

tpl = Template('{{ field }}', autoescape=True)
tpl.render(field=widget)  # '&lt;input type=&#34;text&#34;&gt;'
tpl.render(field=str(widget))  # '<input type="text">'
```

Is it possible to use the widget directly without wrapping it in `str` or calling `render` from within the template? Is there any magic method which I need to override?

Answer (score 1):

After digging through jinja2 and markupsafe source code I found that my widget needs to implement `__html__` magic method which returns the "safe" string.

```py
def __html__(self):
    return self.render()
```